# Vista background only allows solid colors?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, desktop-customization

Last night after a LogMeIn rescue session, I can no longer change my wallpaper in Windows Vista.

It reverted to a plain black background and will only allow me to select solid colors.  When I choose an image for the wallpaper it seems to ignore it.

I ran an anti-virus scan and everything was ok.

It's a 64-bit HP machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure your logmein session is not still "in session". most of those programs take the background out during the session for speed.

Comment: Thank you.  I restarted a few times and did a system restore to 5 minutes before the logmein session. Would a logmein session persist across reboots?

Comment: Possibly. depending on how you reboot. I would check in your system tray to see if logmein is running. if nothing is there check in your prossesses